# How to avoid ViewModel dependency to another ViewModel?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a calendar application where there are 3 main pages :

1. A calendar page that displays calendar contents
2. A settings page that displays user settings
3. An address page that displays list of user addresses

My calendar needs settings and addresses before displaying its content. In the MVVM pattern, I wonder how to avoid a constructor `CalendarViewModel({@required this.SettingsViewModel, @required this.AddressViewModel})` because it seems wierd.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: In MVVM, models should be the focal point. settingViewModel depends on models. Rather than the calenderViewModel depend on another viewmodel, it should depend on those models.

Comment: I see, so the idea is to create top level models that holds data right? So view <= viewmodel <= model?

Comment: exactly @Ado Ren. That's the idea behind MVVM.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I was missing this understanding